Troubleshooting Collapsible Sidebar and Data Fetch Issues in JobFilterSidebar.tsx
enter image description here
I've been trying to make Collapsible function at my aside column.But the location didn't fetch the data, it is only show ALL LOCATIONS. I also has make new action (filterJobs.ts).
Below is my code. JobFilterSidebar.tsx.
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { jobTypes } from "@/lib/job-types";
import { JobFilterValues } from "@/lib/validation";
import { handleFilterJobs } from "../lib/filterJobs"; // Update import
import FormSubmitButton from "./FormSubmitButton";
import { Input } from "./ui/input";
import { Label } from "./ui/label";
import Select from "./ui/select";
import { SlidersHorizontal } from "lucide-react";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";

interface JobFilterSidebarProps {
  defaultValues: JobFilterValues;
}

export default function JobFilterSidebar({
  defaultValues,
}: JobFilterSidebarProps) {
  const [distinctLocations, setDistinctLocations] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocations = async () => {
      const locations = await prisma.job.findMany({
        where: { approved: true },
        select: { location: true },
        distinct: ["location"],
      });



      setDistinctLocations(
        locations.map(({ location }) => location).filter(Boolean) as string[]
      );
    };

    fetchLocations();
  }, []);

  return (
    <aside
      className={`sticky top-5 h-fit overflow-hidden rounded-lg border bg-background transition-all duration-300 md:w-[260px] ${
        isCollapsed ? "h-12 p-2" : "h-fit p-2"
      }`}
    >
      <button
        className="text-custom-gray flex w-full items-center justify-center py-1.5 text-sm font-medium"
        onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
      >
        {isCollapsed ? "Filter" : "Filter"}
        <SlidersHorizontal className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
      </button>

      {!isCollapsed && (
        <form action={handleFilterJobs} key={JSON.stringify(defaultValues)}>
          <div className="space-y-4">
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
              <Label htmlFor="q">Search</Label>
              <Input
                id="q"
                name="q"
                placeholder="Title, company, etc."
                defaultValue={defaultValues.q}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
              <Label htmlFor="type">Type</Label>
              <Select
                id="type"
                name="type"
                defaultValue={defaultValues.type || ""}
              >
                <option value="">All types</option>
                {jobTypes.map((type) => (
                  <option key={type} value={type}>
                    {type}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </div>

            <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
              <Label htmlFor="location">Location</Label>
              <Select
                id="location"
                name="location"
                defaultValue={defaultValues.location || ""}
              >
                <option value="">All locations</option>
                {distinctLocations.map((location) => (
                  <option key={location} value={location}>
                    {location}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </div>

            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
              <input
                id="remote"
                name="remote"
                type="checkbox"
                className="scale-125 accent-black"
                defaultChecked={defaultValues.remote}
              />
              <Label htmlFor="remote">Remote jobs</Label>
            </div>
            <FormSubmitButton className="w-full rounded-lg bg-gray-800 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-gray-700">
              Filter jobs
            </FormSubmitButton>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </aside>
  );
}

